# hiding the path of a file on web server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a webpage that host documents on iis.  When linking to those files for examples say I go to

```
www.webpage.com/Documents/testdocuments/innerfolder/1.pdf
```

I get the file back and have the complete url in the address bar.  Is there a way to be able to browser to

```
www.webpage.com/Documents/testdocuments/innerfolder/1.pdf
```

, and get for example

```
www.webpage.com/Webdocs/1.pdf
```

as the url in the browser.  My theory was make

```
www.webpage.com/Documents
```

a virtual directory, but I am not sure if I would still be able to access my files as

```
www.webpage.com/Documents/testdocuments/innerfolder/1.pdf
```

or if I would have to use for example

```
www.webpage.com/Webdocs/testdocuments/innerfolder/1.pdf
```

which defeats the purpose really.  My ultimate goal is for the physical path of the file to not be visible to the user.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What is your purpose of needing to hide the path from the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking only to map one path to another you should use [IIS url rewriting](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Map Docs" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Webdocs/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="Documents/testdocuments/innerfolder/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The other alternative is [asp.net url routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). But it would be an overkill for what you need.

Comment: +1 for using the URL rewrite module, but I think you have the match and the action URLs the wrong way around. If I've understood the question correctly the request would be for webpage.com/Webdocs/1.pdf which would need to serve the content at webpage.com/Documents/testdocuments/innerfolder/1.pdf - you might also want to add a stopProcessing="true" to the rule to stop it processing any rules that might be added later (even if there aren't any at present).

Comment: @pwdst you are right. I interchanged the match and action. Corrected the answer. Thanks!